# How many labellings are there for a tree on 7 vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I know that Cayleys formula tells us there are $7^5=16807$ unique labelled trees. I also know the 11 trees that form these 16807 different variations.

What I can't calculate is how many of each type of tree there are. If we have a tree where every vertex has order 1 except one vertex which has order 6, then clearly we can only have 7 unique possible labelled trees for this tree.

However when I investigate the tree which has degree sequence $\{1,1,1,1,1,2,5\}$ I do not know how to calculate how many labelled trees this has.

Comment: I believe it to be 210, as the vertex with order 5 has 7 possibilities, the connected vertex with order 2 - we have 6 choices. Then we have 4 like vertices all connected to our 'root'; and one unique vertex, which we now have 5 choices for. 7*6*5 = 210? Is this correct?

Comment: By 'order' do you mean 'degree'? In which case, it seems like you are asking how many trees a degree sequence has. For example, [3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1] has (at least) two trees : 2(3(1)(1))(3(1)(1)) and 3(2(1)(1))(2(1))(1)

Comment: You are correct; that tree has 210 labellings. See my complete answer for more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any graph on $n$ vertices with $k$ *automorphisms* – ways its vertices can be mapped onto themselves to preserve the edges – has $\frac{n!}k$ labellings. Applying this to the trees on seven vertices (the image below taken from Peter Steinbach's *Field Guide to Simple Graphs*, available on the OEIS under the links at [A000055](https://oeis.org/A000055)):

[image]

we see that the trees from left to right have the following numbers of automorphisms:
$$2,2,1,6,8,2,6,4,12,24,720$$
Dividing $7!=5040$ by each number gives the number of labellings of each of these trees:
$$2520,2520,5040,840,630,2520,840,1260,420,210,7$$
As expected, they add up to $7^5=16807$.

---

*Finding the order of the automorphism group of a tree*
As an example, take the second tree from the left. There is only one order-3 vertex, so it must stay fixed in any automorphism. Three paths radiate from this vertex – one of length 4 that must also stay fixed, and two of length 1 that can be swapped. Multiplying the numbers together gives two automorphisms.

For the rightmost star, while the central hub must stay fixed, the six spokes can be permuted in any order, yielding $6!=720$ automorphisms.

Comment: Hi! I was wondering how you are able to know the number of automorphisms of a tree? I didn't study this in class, maybe can you give me some insights?

Comment: @MarineGalantin This is mostly a matter of looking at the tree and finding its global symmetries, then zooming into branches in turn and finding _their_ symmetries recursively, then multiplying the orders of the groups that fall out in that way.

Comment: Would you mind to do a concrete small example? If you have the time now or another time...  I m not sure to understand. For example on the second tree (the path with horns)  and on the last one, the star?

Comment: @MarineGalantin see the bottom section of my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the time and energy in editing this post.